# SWRL - Unable to substract date time by duration

Tags: owl, protege, swrl, pellet

I'm trying to implement a rule that substract 1 years to a datetime and asign it to a data property using only SWRL

I've got an entity `Product` which got a data property `creationDate` equal to `2019-07-15T00:00:00`.

My SWRL rule is the following :

```
Product(?p) ^ creationDate(?p, ?cd) ^ swrlb:yearMonthDuration(?dur, 1, 0) 
^ swrlb:subtractYearMonthDurationFromDateTime(?result, ?cd, ?dur) 
-> Product(?p) ^ yearBeforeCreation(?p, ?result)
```

I expect to get yearBeforeCreation equal to `2018-07-15T00:00:00`

Right now I've tried the SWRL with Pellet and Drools

Thanks for your help !

Comment: why do you have `Product(?p)` in the head of the rule? That's redundant because it's part of the rule body, i.e. one of the requirements that the rule "fires"

Comment: that's a mistake, wasn't paying attention, will correct that in my rule, thx

Answer (score 0):

I manage to make my SWRL work, look like it was something with protege. I've close/open, rewrite my rule and it work.